# What is the proper way to update to the recommended/supported version of Webform CiviCRM module for Drupal 7?

Tags: webform-civicrm

Here is what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to update to the latest version of the Webform CiviCRM, however, for right now the only way for me to update is to deactive the module and unistall it. I don't want to go that route.

What would be the best way for me to do it?

Thank you,
Kevin

Comment: why you need to disable the module? Can't you just replace the module folder and run /update.php or drush up webform_civicrm?

Answer (score 3):

Excellent :-)

You will want to find out where your module lives -> determine whether it lives in /sites/all/modules or in /sites/default/modules

Download a copy of the latest 7.x-5.x from our drupal.org project page: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm

Unpack that tar.gz

Then replace what you have in /sites/all/webform_civicrm or /sites/default/modules/webform_civicrm with that new copy you just downloaded/unpacked using sftp or scp (depending on your access to your site)

Running database updates is a good idea - always do that after you update any module. You can do that by typing /update.php behind your base URL in the browser - or go to Reports -> Status Report and follow link (it should be reporting to you whether there are any pending database updates).